# Categorizing range of numbers in MySql Database Using Python

Tags: python, mysql

I have a table in MySQL with range of week that belong to each person and they looks something like

> (3-15,21-30,33-35)
>
> (3-15)
>
> ( 4-14)
>
> ( 21-30,33-35)

and so on. I want to split each range and put each person in to a category of semesters where the first semester has weeks of 3-19 and semester 2 has 20- 35. If any one had a weeks between 3-15 belongs to semester 1 and if they have a range of week to 35 they belong to both semester.

How can I write Python code for this?

The code I have so far just gets the first 2 characters to identify that it is a digit:

```
import sqlite3
import csv

conn = sqlite3.connect('RefinedDatabase.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()

selectRow = cursor.execute( "SELECT  Weeks FROM staffDataBase")
fetchrow = cursor.fetchone()

while fetchrow != None:

    fetchrow =  str(fetchrow).replace(',)','').replace('(','').replace('u\'','').replace("'","").replace('u"', '').replace('"','').replace(')','')
    if fetchrow[0:2].isdigit  :
        print fetchrow[0:2]
            
    fetchrow = cursor.fetchone()

conn.close()

print ("All Done!!")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to process strings, you should take a little time and learn about regular expressions (https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#module-re)! They are a little frightening initially, but they are an incredible tool.

Take a look at https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall

To get all ranges in your line, you can do something like

```
r = re.findall(r"[0-9]+,[0-9]+", line)
```

And you'll get

```
>>> line = "(3-15,21-30,33-35)"
>>> r = re.findall(r"([0-9]+)\-([0-9]+)", line)
>>> r
[('3', '15'), ('21', '30'), ('33', '35')]
```

You can test regular expressions (and learn) 'live': http://www.regexr.com/
and specifically for python testing: https://regex101.com/

Note: If there are extra characters in your file (eg. spaces) you might have to make the expression slightly more complicated to account for those. Check the `\s` pattern).

Comment: @HimaBhamidipati: Remember to accept the answer if you like it (Click the 'v') so that others know the question has been answered.

Comment: I tried the following code but it prints out only certain number of rows  and gives out the following error: IndexError: list index out of range. I have the following code:

selectRow = cursor.execute( "SELECT  Weeks FROM staffDataBase")
fetchrow = cursor.fetchone()
while fetchrow != None:

 fetchrow =  str(fetchrow).replace(',)','').replace('(','').replace('u\'','').replace("'","").replace('u"', '').replace('"','').replace(')','')
 line = fetchrow
 line = re.findall(r"([0-9]+)\-([0-9]+)", line)
 
 print line[0]
   
 fetchrow = cursor.fetchone()

Comment: I think i know the problem but but how do i rectify it?? i have few entries where there are just  single number in the cell. when i run the code above i just get a empty array as there is no '-' to separate numbers. how do i take this into account??

Comment: First off, you should edit your original question, not put code in your comment. That is just unreadable! Then, you did not implement the code I proposed to you, which does not have the problem with single digits. That code with all the 'replace' function calls is too rigid to be of use.